# Number of iterators depending of a variable with np.nditer

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to iterate over numpy arrays whose the number can be different at each iteration of the program. The goal is to calculate the variance between the same element of these arrays. Here is the code I wrote :

```
for a,s,m  in np.nditer([cost_surfaceS[i].ravel() for i in range(0,len(cost_surfaceS),1)]):
arr = [a, s, m]
    if(float(arr[0]) != float("-inf")):
        variance = np.var(arr,dtype = np.float32)
        variances.append(variance)
    else:
        variances.append(float("-inf"))
```

where cost_surfaceS is a list that contains all my numpy arrays. The issue is that this piece of code works for 3 numpy arrays created and I want to change the "a,s,m" in order to have a number of iterators that depends of the number of numpy arrays created (i.e. `len(cost_surfaceS)`) . Is it a way to do it ?

Comment: Just use `for arr in np.nditer(...)` (and getting rid of the next line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [zip function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is a solution here, as explained by @hpaulj. Working with 2d arrays instead of 1d simply requires to use two times this function, as the following code shows :

```
variances = []
for arr in zip(*cost_surfaceS):
    for element in zip(*arr):
        if(float("-inf") not in element):
            variance = np.var(element, dtype=np.float32)
            variances.append(variance)
        else:
            variances.append(float("-inf"))
```

The `-inf` values are handled by the if condition that avoids computing the variance of arrays containing at least one infinity value.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Bickknght that the unpacking is unnecessary.  Don't use `unpacking` when dealing with an unknown or variable number of elements.

```
In [57]: alist = [np.arange(10), np.arange(10,20), np.arange(20,30)]
```

Making a list of arrays where the we don't need the `ravel`.

```
In [58]: for arr  in np.nditer(alist): 
    ...:     print(arr) 
    ...:                                                                                                        
(array(0), array(10), array(20))
(array(1), array(11), array(21))
(array(2), array(12), array(22))
(array(3), array(13), array(23))
(array(4), array(14), array(24))
(array(5), array(15), array(25))
(array(6), array(16), array(26))
(array(7), array(17), array(27))
(array(8), array(18), array(28))
(array(9), array(19), array(29))
```

Compare this with a straight forward list zip iteration:

```
In [59]: for arr in zip(*alist): 
    ...:     print(arr) 
    ...:                                                                                                        
(0, 10, 20)
(1, 11, 21)
(2, 12, 22)
(3, 13, 23)
(4, 14, 24)
(5, 15, 25)
(6, 16, 26)
(7, 17, 27)
(8, 18, 28)
(9, 19, 29)
```

The difference is that `nditer` makes 0d arrays rather than scalars.  So the elements have a shape (`(0,)`) and `dtype`.  Or in some cases where you want to modify the arrays (but they have to be defined as `read/write`.  Otherwise `nditer` does not offer any real advantages.

```
In [62]: %%timeit 
    ...: ll = [] 
    ...: for arr  in np.nditer(alist): 
    ...:     ll.append(np.var(arr)) 
    ...:                                                                                                        
539 µs ± 17.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [63]: %%timeit 
    ...: ll = [] 
    ...: for arr  in zip(*alist): 
    ...:     ll.append(np.var(arr)) 
    ...:                                                                                                        
524 µs ± 3.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

If you can avoid the Python level loops, things will be lot faster:

```
In [65]: np.stack(alist,1)                                                                                      
Out[65]: 
array([[ 0, 10, 20],
       [ 1, 11, 21],
       [ 2, 12, 22],
       [ 3, 13, 23],
       [ 4, 14, 24],
       [ 5, 15, 25],
       [ 6, 16, 26],
       [ 7, 17, 27],
       [ 8, 18, 28],
       [ 9, 19, 29]])
In [66]: np.var(np.stack(alist,1),axis=1)                                                                       
Out[66]: 
array([66.66666667, 66.66666667, 66.66666667, 66.66666667, 66.66666667,
       66.66666667, 66.66666667, 66.66666667, 66.66666667, 66.66666667])
In [67]: timeit np.var(np.stack(alist,1),axis=1)                                                                
66.7 µs ± 1.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

I've not attempted to test for `-inf`.

===

Another important difference with `nditer`.  It iterates on all elements in a flat sense - in effect it is do the ravel:

Make a list of 2d arrays.

```
In [81]: alist = [np.arange(10.).reshape(2,5), np.arange(10,20.).reshape(2,5), np.arange(20,30.).reshape(2,5)]
```

PLain iteration operates on the first dimension - in this case the 2, so zipped elements are arrays:

```
In [82]: for arr in zip(*alist): 
    ...:     print(arr) 
    ...:                                                                                                        
(array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4.]), array([10., 11., 12., 13., 14.]), array([20., 21., 22., 23., 24.]))
(array([5., 6., 7., 8., 9.]), array([15., 16., 17., 18., 19.]), array([25., 26., 27., 28., 29.]))
```

`nditer` generates the same tuples as in the 1d array case.  Some cases that's fine, but it's hard to avoid if if you don't want it.

```
In [83]: for arr  in np.nditer(alist): 
    ...:     print(arr) 
    ...:                                                                                                        
(array(0.), array(10.), array(20.))
(array(1.), array(11.), array(21.))
(array(2.), array(12.), array(22.))
(array(3.), array(13.), array(23.))
(array(4.), array(14.), array(24.))
(array(5.), array(15.), array(25.))
(array(6.), array(16.), array(26.))
(array(7.), array(17.), array(27.))
(array(8.), array(18.), array(28.))
(array(9.), array(19.), array(29.))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, that's indeed lot easier (and possible) with these approaches. Unfortunately I will be unable to test it within the next 10 days but for the "-inf" I will try with the stack function as this is the fastest and if it does not work, a simple "if" condition with the zip function should work I guess.

Comment: You might want to ask a new question, focusing on how to handle that `-inf` value in a 'vectorized' manner.  The default behavior when encountering the `inf ` is to raise a warning, and return `np.nan`.  I'm not awake enough to tackle that now.